# NHibernate Insert Error

Tags: nhibernate, hilo

I have just setup a Sql Server db using the same mappings and source data that have been working with SQLite, and getting the error below when I try to save a batch of test data.

I suspect it is a hilo issue that SQLite doesn't catch but I can't quite get my brain onto it. I am using the SchemaExport tool to generate the database, which creates a hibernate_unique_key table that is initially '1'. After the error it is '2'

Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
insert into hibernate_unique_key values ( 1 )

insert into hibernate_unique_key values ( 1 )

NHibernate: SELECT this_.ActivitySubjectId as Activity1_3_0_, this_.Description as Descript3_3_0_, 
this_.BusinessId as BusinessId3_0_, this_.ProjectCode as ProjectC6_3_0_ FROM ActivitySubjects this_ WHERE this_.ActivitySubjectType='PROJECT'

NHibernate: select next_hi from hibernate_unique_key with (updlock, rowlock)

NHibernate: update hibernate_unique_key set next_hi = @p0 where next_hi = @p1;@p0 = 2 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)]

NHibernate: INSERT INTO ActivitySubjects (Description, BusinessId, ProjectCode, ActivitySubjectType, ActivitySubjectId) 
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, 'PROJECT', @p3);@p0 = 'Refinish Casino Chairs' [Type: String (75)], @p1 = '006-00-023' [
Type: String (25)], @p2 = '006-00-023' [Type: String (4000)], @p3 = 32768 [Type: Int32 (0)]

NHibernate: INSERT INTO ActivitySubjects (Description, BusinessId, ProjectCode, ActivitySubjectType, 
ActivitySubjectId) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, 'PROJECT', @p3);@p0 = 'Villa Garden Wall Enhancement' 
[Type: String (75)], @p1 = '006-00-024' [Type: String (25)], @p2 = '006-00-024' [Type: String (4000)], @p3 = 32769 [Type: Int32 (0)]

Test 'M:Smack.ConstructionAdmin.Data.Tests.DbConfiguration.TestData.SqlServerDataGenerator.CreateTestDataFile' failed: could not insert: 
[Smack.ConstructionAdmin.Domain.Activities.Subjects.Projects.Project#32769][SQL: INSERT INTO ActivitySubjects 
(Description, BusinessId, ProjectCode, ActivitySubjectType, ActivitySubjectId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'PROJECT', ?)]

NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: 
[Smack.ConstructionAdmin.Domain.Activities.Subjects.Projects.Project#32769]
[SQL: INSERT INTO ActivitySubjects (Description, BusinessId, ProjectCode, ActivitySubjectType, 
    ActivitySubjectId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'PROJECT', ?)] 
    ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 
        'UQ__ActivitySubjects__49555023'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ActivitySubjects'.
The statement has been terminated.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
```

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be with your hilo table. That is behaving correctly from my experience using hilo key generation. According to the exception, you're violating a unique key constraint for ActivitySubjects. Could you provide your class and mapping files?

Comment: @James. Yes, you are right. I have two columns I would ideally like to be unique inside of a table-per-class hiearchy scheme, but which can't be since they belong to different subtypes. I should have known better! If you make your comment an answer I can accept it and close this out. Cheers

Comment: Glad I could help. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't appear to be with your hilo table. That is behaving correctly from my experience using hilo key generation. According to the exception, you're violating a unique key constraint for ActivitySubjects. Check your unique key constraints.